# ScipyOptimizer gives incorrect optimization result

Tags: python, optimization, openmdao

I am running a non-linear optimization problem in [OpenMDAO](http://openmdao.org/), which I know the optimal solution of (I just want to verify the solution). I am using `SLSQP` driver configuration of `ScipyOptimizer` from `openmdao.api`.

I have 3 design variables A, B and C, their respective design-spaces (A<sub>min</sub> to A<sub>max</sub> for A and so on) and a single objective function Z. As I said, I know the optimal values for all the three design variables (let's call them A<sub>sol</sub>, B<sub>sol</sub> and C<sub>sol</sub>) which yield the minimum value of Z (call it Z<sub>sol</sub>).

When I run this problem, I get a value for Z which is larger than Z<sub>sol</sub>, signifying that it is not an optimal solution. When I assign C<sub>sol</sub> to C and run the problem with only A and B as the design variables, I get the value of Z which is much closer to Z<sub>sol</sub> and which is actually lesser than what I got earlier (in 3 design variable scenario).

Why am I observing this behavior? Shouldn't `ScipyOptimizer` give the same solution in both the cases?

EDIT: Adding some code..

```
from openmdao.api import IndepVarComp, Group, Problem
from openmdao.api import ScipyOptimizer

class RootGroup(Group):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RootGroup, self).__init__()

        self.add('desvar_f', IndepVarComp('f', 0.08))
        self.add('desvar_twc', IndepVarComp('tool_wear_compensation', 0.06))
        self.add('desvar_V', IndepVarComp('V', 32.0))
        # Some more config (adding components, connections etc.)

class TurningProblem_singlepart(Problem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TurningProblem_singlepart, self).__init__()

        self.root = RootGroup()

        self.driver = ScipyOptimizer()
        self.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

        self.driver.add_desvar('desvar_f.f', lower=0.08, upper=0.28)
        self.driver.add_desvar('desvar_twc.tool_wear_compensation', lower=0.0, upper=0.5)
        self.driver.add_desvar('desvar_V.V', lower=32.0, upper=70.0)
        self.driver.add_objective('Inverse_inst.comp_output')
        # Other config
```

This code gives me incorrect result. When I remove `desvar_twc` from both the classes, and assign it with its optimal value (from the solution I have), I get fairly correct result i.e. the answer for objective function which is lesser than the previous scenario.

Comment: Can you show us any code?

Comment: Yes, I am putting together code snippets to make it more clear. The actual code is much bigger, that's why I did not put it in the post. I will edit the post shortly.

Comment: Awesome! That always goes a long way :)

Comment: Thanks. :)
Please let me know if you need more explanation for the code.

Comment: Are you expecting this optimizer to do global optimization? `ScipyOptimizer` is a wrapper around `scipy.optimize.minimize`, which does local optimization.

Comment: That was my first guess - that I am getting a local minima. But I tried initializing the `desvar_twc` with the value which is higher than what is in the solution, but it gave me the same (incorrect) result.

As you can see in the code, I have initialized `desvar_twc` with value 0.06 and the optimal solution is 0.05. But running this problem gives me the value 0.00; even though the value of objective function is higher at 0.00 than that of 0.05.

Comment: It could have made too big a step and stepped over the minimum you want, or since this is a multidimensional optimization problem, it could have gone *around* the global minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your actual model, we can't say anything for sure. However, it is *NOT* the case that a local optimizer's solution is independent of the starting condition in general. That is only case if the problem is convex. So I would guess that your problem is not convex, and you'r running into local optima.

You can try to get around this by using the COBYLA optimizer instead of SLSQP, which in my experience can manage to jump over some local optima better. But if your problem is really bumpy, then I would suggest you switch to NSGA-II or ALPSO from the [pyopt-sparse library](https://bitbucket.org/mdolab/pyoptsparse). These are heuristic based optimizers that do a good job of finding the "biggest hill", though they don't always climb all the way to the top of it (they don't converge as tightly). The heuristic algorithms are also generally more expensive than the gradient based methods.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I am trying to run the problem with COBYLA right now, and will update the post with the results. The only thing I was confused about was `desvar_twc=0.05` being the optimal solution, the optimizer gave me 0.00 as the optimal value even when I initialized it with 0.06. What am I missing here?